# Loopless chi-square grid search in Python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, curve-fitting

Best-fit linear parameters A and B (y=Ax+b) correspond to the minimum of the chi-square function over these parameters. I want to do a brute force grid search for the global chi-square minimum (guaranteed because 2-parameter linear chi-square is a paraboloid) and have achieved it with 3 nested loops (below) but want to avoid loops (i.e., vectorize using Numpy's array broadcasting properties).

Chi-square (weighted least squares) is defined as:

```
Chi-square(k,j) = sum (y[i]-(A[k]*x[i]+B[j]))/yerr[i])^2
```

Below is Python Numpy code that fills a 100 x 100 grid with chi-square values over the 10,000 combinations of  A and B parameter values (100 values each). There are three data arrays: x, y and yerr.

Thanks for any help towards a loopless version of a 2-parameter linear chi-square grid search in Python Numpy.

Note I want to do a grid search and not use scipy.optimize.minimize -- thanks!

Keith

```
# create parameter grid
a = np.linspace(80,120,100)
b = np.linspace(10,40,100)
A,B = np.meshgrid(a,b)

# calculate chi-square over parameter grid
chi2=np.zeros((100,100))

for k in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        for i in range (len(y)):
            chi2a = ((y[i]-a[k]*x[i]-b[j])/yerr[i])**2;
            chi2[k,j]+=chi2a;
```

Comment: Indentation for the last line looks wrong. Also, shouldn't it be `chi2[k,j]+= chi2a` instead?

Comment: Yes to both comments (now edited).  Thank you for catching this!

Comment: Think we need two more tab indentations there, as we need to sum update for each computation of `chi2a`.

Comment: Also, `range(1,100)` should be `range(100)` and son on to cover all elements.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  Just tested the script with your corrections and it appears to run fine now.  Thanks again.

Comment: Seems like one more tiny edit is needed : `for i in range (len(y)):` again to cover all elements.

Comment: Corrected -- sincere thanks from a Python beginner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach making use of [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
subs = (y-a[:,None,None]*x-b[:,None])/yerr
chi2 = (subs**2).sum(2)
```

Here's another and possibly faster one with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
chi2 = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',subs,subs) #subs from previous one
```